# zlib option Z_NO_COMPRESSION results in larger file

Tags: encoding, compression, zlib, huffman-code

I am trying to use zlib 1.2.7 for pure Huffman coding, so I'm calling `deflateInit2` with Z_NO_COMPRESSION and Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY. Everything runs fine, and I've verified that it can be inflated back to the same contents.

However, the resulting bytestream (as measured in `c_stream.total_out`) is **larger** than the original contents (by < 5%). This occurs even if I pass in Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY instead of Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY. Can someone point me where my thinking or code has gone wrong?

```
z_stream c_stream;
c_stream.zalloc = (alloc_func)0;
c_stream.zfree = (free_func)0;
c_stream.opaque = (voidpf)0;

err = deflateInit2(&c_stream, Z_NO_COMPRESSION, Z_DEFLATED, 15, 8, Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY);
CHECK_ERR(err, "deflateInit2");

comprLen  = deflateBound(&c_stream, uncomprLen);
Byte *compr = (Byte *)calloc(comprLen * sizeof(Byte), 1); 

c_stream.next_out = compr;
c_stream.avail_out = (uInt)comprLen;
c_stream.next_in = uncompr;
c_stream.avail_in = (uInt)uncomprLen;

err = deflate(&c_stream, Z_FINISH);
if (err != Z_STREAM_END) {
    fprintf(stderr, "deflate should report Z_STREAM_END\n");
    exit(1);
}
comprLen = c_stream.total_out;
err = deflateEnd(&c_stream);
CHECK_ERR(err, "deflateEnd");
```

Comment: You're telling it not to compress anything, so it's going to copy the original contents verbatim -- "0 gives no compression at all (the input data is simply copied a block at a time)". On top of that, there will be overhead of the zlib format, so yeah, it's going to end up larger.

Comment: Additionally, I should have mentioned I was using an old version of the library. I think this was at least partially unexpected behavior between the conflicting flags which was resolved in 2016 https://github.com/madler/zlib/commit/94575859cf7f657f0f31aff4c50761fe3f182699

Comment: You should [edit] your question, and that info there.

Answer (score 0):

First off, asking for no compression and Huffman compression at the same time is a contradiction. Which do you want? For no compression, use `Z_NO_COMPRESSION` and `Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY`. For Huffman-only compression, use `Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION` and `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY`. Pick one of those.

Since you are using that older version of zlib, the contradictory options should result in the `Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY` taking precedence. Lossless compression of any kind is never guaranteed to compress. Try a sequence of zero bytes to verify that you're doing it all correctly, in which case you will get about a factor of eight compression.

If after that your data expands after Huffman compression, then it is simply that your data is not compressible that way. That means you have a roughly flat distribution of all 256 byte values in your data.

And yes, of course you'll get expansion with no compression (`Z_NO_COMPRESSION` and `Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY`), on the order of 0.01%.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted Huffman compression (only). Despite the older version, it seems that "no compression" was taking precedence because I now see compression instead of expansion when using Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION and Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY. I wondered if that was because of the change in trees.c here https://github.com/madler/zlib/commit/56bcb184fac036a45cb8937238d51778d0a796aa ?